React Virtual DOM: Creation process from React.createElement() to ReactDOM rendering?
I'm trying to understand the process of how React's Virtual DOM is created and its relationship with React.createElement(). My current understanding is:

React.createElement() calls (often generated from JSX) create a tree
of React elements.
This tree of elements somehow becomes the Virtual DOM. The ReactDOM
package is involved in creating the Virtual DOM.

But React.createElement() is part of the React package, not ReactDOM.
Here's a simple example to illustrate my confusion:
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>World</p>
    </div>
  );
}

This JSX would be transformed into React.createElement() calls, but how exactly does this become the Virtual DOM?
My questions are:

Is the Virtual DOM directly created from the React.createElement()
calls, or is there an intermediate step?
What exactly is the role of ReactDOM in this process? Are there any
good resources that explain this process in detail?

I've found the React documentation a bit unclear on this specific topic, so I'd appreciate any clarification or pointers to reliable sources.

I find this article really helpful in explaining the relationship between React elements and the React DOM; did you come across it when you were browsing the docs? https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit
The article establishes two steps in the react DOM process, 'render' and 'commit'.
Render

Is the Virtual DOM directly created from the React.createElement() calls, or is there an intermediate step?

The react-dom gets created when you instantiate it with the render at this initialization step, which occurs in the root index.js file in a standard react app:


import Image from './Image.js';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(<Image />);



Commit
React internally manages re-rendering and updating the DOM, also called reconciliation. That's why we don't need a subsequent method like root.rerender() to be called here.
Although this article calls it the 'virtual DOM', it's the same as the 'React DOM' you are referring to here, and explains reconciliation in depth.
